# C++ managed wrapper called from C#

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, managed-c++, dllexport

I have some native C++ code and I have then created a wrapper to go around it.
creator.h

```
#pragma once
#include "file.h"
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
class EXPORT creator{
public:
  creator();
  ~creator();
  bool function1(int);
  bool startFunction1(char *in, char *cache, char *out, long, double);
};
```

wrapper.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace nativeWrapper
{
public ref class Wrapper{
public:
creator *c;
Wrapper();
~Wrapper();
bool wStartCreating(System::String ^_in, System:: ^_cache, System:: ^_out);
};
}
```

wrapper.cpp
Lets just go straight to the wStartCreating function

```
bool Wrapper::wStartCreating(System::String ^_in, System:: ^_cache, System:: ^_out)
{
char *in = marshaling(_in);
char *out = marshaling(_out);
char *cache = marshaling(_cache);
return c->startFunction(in, cache, out, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

in the c# code:

```
[DllImport("wrapper.dll")]
private static extern bool wStartCreating(String _in, String cache, String _out);
```

Then, I want to call wStartCreating(String, String, String) but I get a dllnotfoundexception whenever I try to make the call. I tried to add the reference (by the way this is in Visual studio 2005) and in the build event I copied the dll over to the referenced folder. Need some help as to why this runtime error may be coming up. 
Thanks
-Tommy

Comment: You neglected to give us the runtime error that you are getting. Nevermind I see the reference to dllnotfound exception now. Sry mised it first time through.

Comment: Just guessing, but you are missing a quote in the DllImport attribute and Since you are not including a full path, the dll will have to be in the same folder as the application calling it.

Comment: I guess I could be more specific: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'wrapper.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESuLT: 0x8007007E) at csharpgui.csharpconverter.wStartCreating(String in, String cache, String out) at csharpgui.csharpconverter.CallmadeContainingwStartCreating() in file.cs

Comment: After your compile, is wrapper.dll present in the folder with the calling application?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the build events, to copy what is needed to the proper directories

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific as well... after you compile your C# application (lets say for example a Debug compile). Do wrapper.dll and any requisits that it may have end up in the Debug folder along with the application?

Comment: It copies creator.dll and wrapper.dll over to the debug folder. If creator calls others should I try to move those over too?

Comment: Is this a desktop app, or a web app?

Comment: This is a desktop application

Comment: Ok, all dependencies will have to be located either in the path described by the PATH encivonment variable, or in the folder with the binaries of the calling application or Windows will not be able to find them. The only exception to this is .Net dependencies that are in the GAC.

Comment: I'm suspecting that moving the dll files over to the debug file worked since now I get a new error that I get to debug through. "LoaderLock was detected" in one of the other DLL Files that is being used.